# Textview does not support base 64 decoding Android

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I have some content encoded in base64 from my server.

When I get a response and try to decode it, it does not show new lines and spaces encoded in the content.

The below code decodes properly, but when I set it as the text of the textview, no new lines or spaces are shown in content decoded.

However, saving the content decoded in sqlite and viewing in sqlite browser notepad show the text correctly.

```
String base64data = response.getString("data");
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64data, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text1 = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

**My decoded content is like:**

In typography, the point is the smallest unit of measure. It is used for measuring font size, leading, and other items on a printed page. The size of the point has varied throughout the history of printing. Since the 18th century, the point's size has varied from 0.18 to 0.4 millimeters.

1. 1P̸2p (12 points would be just "1P̸")—traditional style
2. 1p2 (12 points would be just "1p")—format for desktop
3. 14pt (12 points would be "12pt" or "1pc" since it is the same as 1 pica)—format used by Cascading Style Sheets defined by the World Wide Web Consortium[3]

A typographic or printer's foot contains 72 picas or 864 points. The Metric Act of 1866 established a legal ratio of 1200 : 3937 between the foot and the meter.[4] For the survey foot used prior to 1959, this was 0.0002% more than 304.8 mm, the length of the international foot established by the 1959 International Yard and Pound Agreement.

**And in textview,it is showing like this:**

In typography, the point is the smallest unit of measure. It is used for measuring font size, leading, and other items on a printed page. The size of the point has varied throughout the history of printing. Since the 18th century, the point's size has varied from 0.18 to 0.4 millimeters. 1. 1P̸2p (12 points would be just "1P̸")—traditional style 2. 1p2 (12 points would be just "1p")—format for desktop 3. 14pt (12 points would be "12pt" or "1pc" since it is the same as 1 pica)—format used by Cascading Style Sheets defined by the World Wide Web Consortium[3] A typographic or printer's foot contains 72 picas or 864 points. The Metric Act of 1866 established a legal ratio of 1200 : 3937 between the foot and the meter.[4] For the survey foot used prior to 1959, this was 0.0002% more than 304.8 mm, the length of the international foot established by the 1959 International Yard and Pound Agreement.

Comment: Can you provide content which you are trying to insert to TextView?

Comment: Content is private.so i can not show it publically sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the cause of your problem without content but there are some advices which can help you.

First, use TextView with enough size. Something like this one:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

I suppose you use `\n` symbol as line break. So when you are adding your text, replace `\n` symbols with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. Something like this:

```
String text1 = new String(data, "UTF-8");
String string = text1.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

As alternative you can use SpannableString.

Comment: I have edited my code ..Please see the content @comrade

Comment: I have tried what you adviced to me,but got no solution.Now i have edited my post so that you can better understand my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While decoding your `base64data` try to use other flags.
I guess `Base64.NO_WRAP` is what you want. You can also see other flags from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: May it exist an option in server side also while encoding?

Comment: it's default on server side.So i am also using default on andorid end

Comment: Is your server also Java? By the way, I almost sure your problem is becuse of these flags

Comment: String s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 
                                         Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);

Comment: where should i use it?? i am not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116037/discussion-between-mismanc-and-shivani-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

I found a  Simple but strange answer :

```
String base64data = response.getString("data");
                byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64data,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                String decoded_text= new String(data, "UTF-8");
                decoded_text=decoded_text.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "WRAP");
                decoded_text=decoded_text.replaceAll("WRAP","\n\r");
                textview.setText(decoded_text);
```

Thanks